# How can I make my loop move on to the next workbook without repeating itself in the first workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I just want to insert 3 rows with formulas but these rows keep inserting over and over again in the first opened workbook.

For the sake of discussion, would it be better to use a For Each loop instead?

```
Sub FXBuy()

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim PathName$, FileName$

    PathName = "H:\BASEL Reporting - Oliver's Mock\FX\"
    FileName = Dir(PathName)
    Do While FileName <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName)

wb.Sheets("FX").Columns("W:X").Hidden = True
wb.Sheets("FX").Columns("AD:AI").Hidden = True

wb.Sheets("FX").Columns("U:AB").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = 65535
 

LastRow = wb.Sheets("FX").Columns("B").Find("B", LookAt:=xlPart).MergeArea.Row + wb.Sheets("FX").Columns("B").Find("B", LookAt:=xlPart).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1

wb.Sheets("FX").Range("A" & LastRow & ":A" & LastRow + 2).EntireRow.Insert

wb.Sheets("FX").Range("S" & LastRow) = 20
wb.Sheets("FX").Range("S" & LastRow + 1) = 50

wb.Sheets("FX").Range("U" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,U$3:U$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
wb.Sheets("FX").Range("Z" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,Z$3:Z$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
wb.Sheets("FX").Range("AB" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,AB$3:AB$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"

wb.Sheets("FX").Range("U" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,U$3:U$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
wb.Sheets("FX").Range("Z" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,Z$3:Z$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
wb.Sheets("FX").Range("AB" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,AB$3:AB$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"

wb.Sheets("FX").Range("U" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(U" & LastRow & ",U" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
wb.Sheets("FX").Range("Z" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(Z" & LastRow & ",Z" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
wb.Sheets("FX").Range("AB" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(AB" & LastRow & ",AB" & LastRow + 1 & ")"

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `wb` so `wb.worksheets("SheetName").Range....`

Comment: Excel cannot know in which workbook/worksheet `Columns` and `Range` objects are located unless you tell VBA explicitly! Never use them without specifying what workbook/worksheet you exactly mean to use. Otherwise it uses Excels default which might be something else than you expect.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, what if my workbooks have different sheet names?

Comment: You'll need to change "sheetname" to what you require.

Comment: The loop is still getting stuck even after I have added in the workbook and worksheet declaration in front of each range. It should be fairly straightforward but somehow my loop is still getting stuck iterating in the first workbook. What am I missing here?

Comment: please update the code in your question we can only help if we see what you did. Note that if your sheet names change you can also use the sheets position eg. if it is always the first sheet `Worksheets(1)` will do it.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, I've amended my code above. Noted on your suggestion to use the sheets position as an identifier as well. For now I am testing my code on only 2 workbooks, both with the same sheet name but the iteration still gets stuck in the first workbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would highly benefit from a `With wb.Sheets("FX")` statement so you don't need to repeat that 100 times.

Your issue is that you need a `FileName = Dir()` right before Loop to move to the next file.

```
Public Sub FXBuy()
    Dim PathName As String
    PathName = "H:\BASEL Reporting - Oliver's Mock\FX\"
    
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Dir(PathName)
    
    Do While FileName <> vbNullString
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName)

        With wb.Worksheets("FX")  ' this is used by every statement that starts with a dot
            .Columns("W:X").Hidden = True
            .Columns("AD:AI").Hidden = True

            .Columns("U:AB").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = 65535
 
            LastRow = .Columns("B").Find("B", LookAt:=xlPart).MergeArea.Row + .Columns("B").Find("B", LookAt:=xlPart).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1

            .Range("A" & LastRow & ":A" & LastRow + 2).EntireRow.Insert

            .Range("S" & LastRow) = 20
            .Range("S" & LastRow + 1) = 50

            .Range("U" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,U$3:U$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
            .Range("Z" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,Z$3:Z$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
            .Range("AB" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,AB$3:AB$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"

            .Range("U" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,U$3:U$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
            .Range("Z" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,Z$3:Z$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
            .Range("AB" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,AB$3:AB$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"

            .Range("U" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(U" & LastRow & ",U" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
            .Range("Z" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(Z" & LastRow & ",Z" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
            .Range("AB" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(AB" & LastRow & ",AB" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
        End With
            
        FileName = Dir() ' move to next file
    Loop
End Sub
```

If different workbooks have different sheets you can do something like below:

Note that workbook names must contain the file extension!

```
Public Sub FXBuy()
    Dim PathName As String
    PathName = "H:\BASEL Reporting - Oliver's Mock\FX\"
    
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Dir(PathName)
    
    Do While FileName <> vbNullString
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName)
        
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Select Case wb.Name  ' workbook names must be with file extension
            Case "FX BUY.xslm":
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets("FX BUY")
            
            Case "other workbook.xslm":
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets("other worksheet")

            Case Else:  ' for all other workbooks use this default
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets("FX")
        End Select

        With ws  ' this is used by every statement that starts with a dot
            .Columns("W:X").Hidden = True
            .Columns("AD:AI").Hidden = True

            .Columns("U:AB").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = 65535
 
            LastRow = .Columns("B").Find("B", LookAt:=xlPart).MergeArea.Row + .Columns("B").Find("B", LookAt:=xlPart).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1

            .Range("A" & LastRow & ":A" & LastRow + 2).EntireRow.Insert

            .Range("S" & LastRow) = 20
            .Range("S" & LastRow + 1) = 50

            .Range("U" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,U$3:U$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
            .Range("Z" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,Z$3:Z$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
            .Range("AB" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.2,AB$3:AB$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"

            .Range("U" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,U$3:U$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
            .Range("Z" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,Z$3:Z$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"
            .Range("AB" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUMIF($K$3:$K$" & LastRow - 1 & ",0.5,AB$3:AB$" & LastRow - 1 & ")"

            .Range("U" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(U" & LastRow & ",U" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
            .Range("Z" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(Z" & LastRow & ",Z" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
            .Range("AB" & LastRow + 2).Formula = "=SUM(AB" & LastRow & ",AB" & LastRow + 1 & ")"
        End With
            
        FileName = Dir() ' move to next file
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ, your answer worked great, it seemed that I was only missing that line of code. 

Anyway, if I need to have a separate section of code for a specific workbook/s, how should I go about it? I have tried adding 
`If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "FX BUY" Then *additional code*` 
but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @OliverTheseira see my edit. You need to include the file extension.

Comment: Minor typo, but I think the extension for macro-enabled worksheets should be .xlsm. Additionally, I was actually asking for the case when I needed to perform a different operation on a specific file. Nevertheless, If-Then worked, all I was missing was the file extension. 

Separate question - how do I account for multiple wildcards in the FileName statement, e.g. when I only want my code to run for FX Buy/Sell and 3RD CRCY BUY/SELL files. I know how the declaration works with 1 wildcard `FileName = Dir(PathName & "*FX*")` but not sure how to include multiple wildcards in this statement.

Comment: As far as I know you can't. Therefore you would need 2 loops one for `*FX*` and one for `*3RD CRCY*`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you have several Excel files in the path "H:\BASEL Reporting - Oliver's Mock\FX" and you want to run the code for each of them

Your mistake is simply that you never change the "FileName" variable.

```
FileName = Dir(PathName) ' Find first file in path
Do While FileName <> ""  ' As long as that file is not nothing
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName) ' Open it as an Excel.Workbook
```

I'd recommend to not use the Dir() function at all, because it is deprecated. If you still want to use it, you have to run `FileName = Dir()` to get the next file name. It should work, when you do it just before the "Loop" command.

Comment: How is the [Dir function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) deprecated? Any source about that? Because the documentation still lists it as valid function. • And what would you use instead (that works on **both** Windows and Mac)?

Comment: Which function would you recommend to use as an alternative to Dir() in my scenario?

Comment: @OliverTheseira Actually no other than `Dir()`. It does perfectly what you want. See my answer. `Dir()` has one big advantage: It works on both Windows and Mac. Alternatives will only work on Windows. So I would stick with `Dir()` because there is nothing wrong using it.